# Filter results of get_terms() in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, filtering, taxonomy

I am displaying a list of faculty members with some custom field information from a custom taxonomy called "faculty-members". The name of each term is the full name of the faculty member, so when I order by name using get_terms(), I get an alphabetical list based on first name. I know I can filter get_terms(). but I can't figure out if there is any way I can filter my array of returned objects so that it picks up the last name from the name field and sorts it that way? As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, this is what the first two returned objects look like

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 44 [name] => Abigail McKenzie [slug] => abigail-mckenzie [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 47 [taxonomy] => faculty-member [description] => Abigail McKenzie has a BFA in painting from the Cleveland Institute of Art, and an MA and MFA in printmaking from the University of Iowa. She is currently the chairman of the Art Department at Flint Hill School in Oakton, Virginia. [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 7 [name] => Amanda Dalla Villa Adams [slug] => amanda-dalla-villa-adams [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 10 [taxonomy] => faculty-member [description] => Amanda Dalla Villa Adams is a current doctoral student in art history at Virginia Commonwealth University, received her BFA in sculpture from VCU, and her MA in art history from the University of Cincinnati. [parent] => 0 [count] => 3 )
```

Comment: can you paste your returned object in here ?

Comment: Hi @wordpresser, I have added a sample to my post. Thanks!

Comment: you cant accomplish it through standard wordpress function as `last_name` is not a column / field to be sorted .

Comment: Thanks @wordpresser, I was afraid of that. If they were to add in a last_name custom field for sorting purposes, how would I latch on to that to perform the sort?

Comment: okey so i did a quick google and found this link helpful .. http://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/

Comment: but still you cant sort by custom fields

Comment: you should also have a look here http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-taxonomy-sort/